# What does it mean by "they see me rollin', they hatin'"?

Tags: meaning

I have seen a lot of teenagers nowadays going by the lingo "They see me rollin', they hatin'". I'm sure they use it to address their haters but what does it necessarily imply when they relate themselves to a 'rolling' action?

Comment: I think one needs context. Rolling can be riding, sure. But the two do not necessarily go together unless you can provide specific usage.

Comment: This sense of "roll" is (now) in [the dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/roll): "2.9 *informal no object* Behave in a particular way. ‘that's just how I roll, guys—I'll smile until I physically can't’"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Rolling` could mean driving/cruising around specifically or it could also be taken in a much more general sense to mean "conducting myself (publicly)".

Google around for the expression "that's how I roll".  Also see the music video by Chamillionaire "Riding Dirty" - or much better yet, its parody by Weird Al Yankovic: "White and Nerdy".

Answer (score 8):

It refers to Chamillionaire's song "Ridin". In it the rapper criticizes police for discriminating certain groups of people (afroamericans and latins).

In short, the police sees a black person "ridin" his car, hates him for having his financial condition, supposes a black person only would have such money through crime, then stops him, only to be frustrated by the fact that he is a hard working american citizen.

Nowadays it is commonly used in the internet to refer to "haters", people who blindly criticize certain people or points of view out of pure dogmatism.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about jealousy, someone is talking to his jealous haters, saying that I am becoming more famous or wealthier or whatever and you are hating me because you're jealous